# Construct inner allocator from a scoped allocator adaptor

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

Recently I started using the boost implementation of the C++11 scoped allocator concept. Now I get puzzled how to use scoped allocator adaptors with containers having a nesting level of more than one. Especially how to propagate the allocators in the scoped allocator adaptors properly to the nested ones and how to retrieve a correct inner allocator to pass to objects later to be moved in?

To be more precise. The problem I encounter is the following. Having a `vector<vector<int>>`, I can do something like

```
namespace bco = boost::container;
typedef std::allocator<int> Alloc1;
typedef bco::vector<int, Alloc1 > Vec1;

typedef bco::scoped_allocator_adaptor<std::allocator<Vec1>, 
std::allocator<Vec1>> Alloc2;

typedef bco::vector<Vec1, Alloc2 > Vec2;
```

and move a Vec1 in Vec2 using

```
Alloc2 alloc2;
Vec2 vec2(alloc2);
vec2.push_back(boost::move(Vec1(alloc2.inner_allocator())));
```

But if I add one more level and try the same, it will not work any longer

```
typedef bco::scoped_allocator_adaptor<std::allocator<Vec2>,
std::allocator<Vec2>, std::allocator<Vec2> > Alloc3;

typedef bco::vector<Vec2, Alloc3 > Vec3;

 Alloc3 alloc3;
 Vec3 vec3(alloc3);
 vec3.push_back(Vec2(alloc3.inner_allocator()));
```

The push will not compile as the allocator in the construction of a Vec2 is not the type expected. This is no surprise as the allocator can't know it. The following is for example also valid code propagating an allocator.

```
typedef bco::scoped_allocator_adaptor< std::allocator<Vec2> > Alloc3b;
typedef bco::vector<Vec2, Alloc3b > Vec3b;
```

So far so good, but I see no way to convert the allocator to the type required. Using rebind only changes the type allocated but not the allocator type itself. So I'm missing the magic to convert a scoped allocator adaptor to an other one. Normally one don't care as the allocator traits construct function will take care of it. To be sure however, that an object to be moved in uses the correct allocator I need to get the corresponding inner allocator somehow from the "main" scoped allocator adaptor. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Short form, change your typedef for Alloc3:

```
typedef bco::scoped_allocator_adaptor< std::allocator<Vec2>, 
                                       std::allocator<Vec1>, 
                                       std::allocator<int> > Alloc3;

Alloc3 alloc3;
Vec3 vec3(alloc3);
vec3.push_back(Vec2(alloc3.inner_allocator()));
```

The reason it didn't work without the change is that the inner allocator for your original implementation was `bco::scoped_allocator_adaptor< std::allocator<Vec2>, std::allocator<Vec2>>`.  When constructing one `scoped_allocator_adaptor` from another, all of the template arguments except the first have to be the same.   In the original case giving you problems, this was not the case, hence the compiler error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It works.For it to work however, I have to know the implementation details down to Vec1. Especially I have to define every allocator down to the required nesting level and cannot use a definition like used in Alloc3b. The issue seems to convert a allocator of type `Vec3::allocator_type::inner_allocator_type` to a 
`Vec3::value_type::allocator_type`. This magic must somehow be done by the allocator_traits construct function, but I'm not able to figure out how it does the trick.

Comment: @mmathes:  Well, the 'magic' is that a scoped_allocator_adaptor has OuterAllocator (the first allocator in it's type list) as a base class.  This allows it to be passed to a container that expects OuterAllocator, which performs a slice.